# Swift 4 Call ViewWillAppear after dismissing View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I would like to call `viewWillAppear` after dismissing a layover `ViewController`.

`ViewController1` -> `Segue` -> `ViewController2`

**In VeiwController2**

1.)

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2.)

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

       ViewController1().viewWillAppear(true)

    }
```

**In VeiwController1**

When `viewWillAppear` is called im getting `null` errors crashing my app. How can i dismiss a `overContext` `ViewController` and call the `viewWillAppear` method in a correct manner.

Comment: can you show me

Comment: When you call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` from `ViewController2` automatically `viewWillAppear` of `ViewController1` will be called. you don't need to call `viewWillAppear` manually.

Comment: As said, don't call `viewWillAppear()` Also, `ViewController1()` is creating a WHOLE NEW object, and its not the one you think of, and also it's not linked with all the UI (IBOutlet etc.) in the storyboard, so you should clearly get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" (because IBOutlets are nil).

Comment: yes thats exactly whats happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

viewWillAppear is called automatically when you dismiss VC2. Delete:
`ViewController1().viewWillAppear(true)`

Try deleting:

`super.viewWillAppear(animated)` in VC1.
[viewDidAppear not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532808/viewdidappear-not-getting-called?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Does it even go back to your VC? self.dismiss works with "Present Modally" segue here. Or embed in NavigationBar, with popViewController

Comment: still not calling it

Comment: Does it even go back to your VC? self.dismiss works with "Present Modally" segue here (change the segue). Or embed in NavigationBar, with popViewController. Then view will appear.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'the problem was the Segue' @husharoonie? I have a similar problem. Can't figure out the answer.

Comment: @LateNate if you push to another controller you can go back by typing 'navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)'. Self.dismiss doesn't work. Self.dismiss works with modal presentation style 'present(secondController, animated: true)'

Comment: Thanks @Kowboj. I found a less than ideal solution to this myself using NSNotificationCenter. Rather than using ViewWillAppear to update after dismissing I used a notification observer. Didn't want to do it that way, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Override this function in ViewController1
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

 //Your code here will execute after viewDidLoad() or when you dismiss the child viewController  

}
```

I'd suggest you go through the life cycle of ViewController.
[Apple documentation for ViewController life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)

Comment: it still doesnt call viewWillAppear when i dismiss

Comment: Could you share the project link ?

Answer (score 1):

yout modal should be .fullScreen

Try with this:

```
let createAccounts = CreateAccounts();
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: createAccounts)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```